# AxisFault: Namespace mismatch error when called from certain client such as Docuware

Tags: apache, tomcat, soap, namespaces, apache-axis

I have a SOAP web service built with Axis 2 on a Tomcat 9 and it works so good so far when requesting from the testing tool (SOAPUI) and with custom clients built with Netbeans.

But when I make a request from a BPM called Docuware I get this error:

[image]

Error:

```
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: namespace mismatch require http://ws.apache.org/axis2 found http://ws.apache.org/axis2/
```

As far as I know the namespace is defined in the wsdl file, which seems to match the required URL (the one without the slash):

[image]

(Click to expand image)

Any thoughts? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the client (Docuware in this case) is sending the namespace with a final slash (this is the found namespace), so It difeers from the wsdl namespace (the required).

I fixed It by changing the required **Service Target Namespace** and the **Schema Target Namespace** in making It coincide with the **found** namespace by editing the **services.xml** file.

Changed

```
<service name="ServicioPrueba">
```

to

```
<service name="ServicioPrueba" targetNamespace="http://ws.apache.org/axis2/">
```

and added inside the service tag:

```
<schema schemaNamespace="http://ws.apache.org/axis2/" />
```

So now the wsdl gets custom generated target namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

In DocuWare you define the url of the webservices in Configuration--> Integrations --> WebServers, so, you can change from the DocuWare interface.